# Remove Duplicate values in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have the below table and I need to remove the duplicate values and leave the values only for the last session, example if an anonymous_id has 1,2,3,4 sessions_group I just need session_group 4.

channel_to_order table

[image: 1]

```
select ANONYMOUS_ID, order_number,session_group_b2, CHAN_ATTRIBUTION, max (session_group) as last_session
from channel_to_order
where session_group = session_group_b2 
group by order_number,ANONYMOUS_ID, session_group_b2, CHAN_ATTRIBUTION;
```

The above query is giving me the last session however I'm still having some duplicate values, not sure how to solve this  I have also tried

```
select * from(
select cto.*, row_number() over (partition by  order_number order by  ANONYMOUS_ID ) as rn
  from channel_to_order cto)
  where rn = 1
;
```

In this case I do not have duplicates however the results are not showing the last session_group also I have been told to not use `partition by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following query to remove duplicates and get the last `session_group`:

```sql
select ANONYMOUS_ID, order_number, CHAN_ATTRIBUTION, max(session_group) as last_session
from channel_to_order
where session_group = session_group_b2 
group by ANONYMOUS_ID, order_number, CHAN_ATTRIBUTION
```

This query uses the group by clause to group the records by `ANONYMOUS_ID`, `order_number`, and `CHAN_ATTRIBUTION`. The max function is used to get the maximum value of `session_group` for each group. Since you only want to keep the last session, this is equivalent to getting the last `session_group`.